# Cloned screen on monitors with different resolutions

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, resolution, clone

I want to set up a system with two displays connected.  One display will be a 22inch monitor with a native resolution of 1920x1080.  The other display is a 19inch display native resolution 1024x768.

I want to clone the 1920x1080 display on to the 1024x768 display.

I have tried this and the 1080p image is squashed on to the smaller display.  Is it possible to set it up such that rather than squashing the image, I can get the smaller display to use a virtual resolution of 1920x1080 and pan the display?

Answer (score 0):

Windows mirroring demands that both monitors be of the same resolution.

The solution is a commercial product - [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) ($39.95).

From its documentation about [Mirroring](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/mirroring.asp) :

> UltraMon offers a very flexible
>   software mirroring solution:
>
> - mirror to one or more monitors
> - mirror only a single application, part of the desktop, or the area
>     around the mouse pointer
> - zoom the mirror image or flip it horizontally and/or vertically
> - the source monitor can run at a higher resolution than the mirror
>     monitor
> - pause mirroring (freezes the current image on the mirror monitor)
> - use hotkeys to start/stop/pause mirroring
> - source and mirror monitors can be driven by different video cards

Comment: To the downvoter : Windows has certainly changed since 2010 when this answer was written. Take some care how you distribute your downvotes.