# Problem mirroring two monitors with different resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, mirroring, ultramon

I am trying to put two monitors in mirror mode (Windows 7 Professional) with Ultramon 3.1.0.

The two monitors:

- Main monitor: 24" Asus. 1680x1050 resolution (16/10).
- Secondary monitor: 19" LG. 1280x1024 resolution.

The graphic card is a Nvidia GeForce 8600 GT.

I have installed the Ultramon 3.1.0 and I have created a mirror, with the "stretch mirror image to fill monitor" and the "disable video overlays and 3D acceleration".
When I start the mirroring, there are two zones in the lateral edges that are not displayed in the second monitor. I think this is because the width of the main monitor is 1680 px. and the width of the secondary monitor is 1280 px., but I have indicated "stretch mirror image to fill monitor" in the options. The same occurs in the top and the bottom edges, but the diference is minimal (1050 vs 1024 pixels).

I want the same image (distortioned in the secondary monitor if is neccesary), but I don't know what is failing.

Someone can help me, please?

I have read

- [Mirrored monitors of different resolution](https://superuser.com/questions/70927/mirrored-monitors-of-different-resolution)
- [Cloned screen on monitors with different resolutions](https://superuser.com/questions/125314/cloned-screen-on-monitors-with-different-resolutions)

Comment: Make the smaller your primary?

Comment: If i make the smaller monitor my primary monitor I have black slides in the sides, in the top and in the bottom, bacause Ultramon doesn't stretch mirror image to fill monitor :(

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you can clone a display using display properties without involving ultramon.  I know I did it with XP when hooking to a projector before buying ultramon.