# NVIDIA DSR factors not present - trying to have a fake 4K into a 1080p

Tags: video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, 4k-resolution, 1080p

I just follow few liks, like this one:
[Cloning a 4K panel to a 1080p monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/1371923/cloning-a-4k-panel-to-a-1080p-monitor)

to fake a 4k monitor into a 1080p display

REASON: I want to have the 1080p monitor as second monitor, but APPs are too BIG, interfaces takes most of screen

Actually I have a third virtual monitor with amyuni usbmmidd_v2
https://www.amyuni.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3030
and OBS casting that third monitor into the second

But setup is far from perfect:

- SLOW, you see delay on the second monitor
- BRAKE changing windows account (i do it like 4 or 5 times a day)

so, I search, and I found about the DSR factors
but mine is not showed

CARD is Quadro K2200 with drivers 537.13
some configs:
Vertical sync OFF
3D stereo OFF
Bios version 82.07.5a.00.08
Image Scaling On

Something I am missing?
any other alternative or idea to fake a 4K into a 1080p?